# How to verify http call is being made from IOS/Android/Kindle/Windows devices

Tags: android, ios, security

I have an app on multiple  platforms and i want to add a check to make sure the call is happening from the app. How can i verify this?

The app is a video game which is trying to post high scores back to the server which receives https calls.
The calls should be as secure as possible since i dont want people to post insane scores by decompiling any of the apk.

Update...
I found something for android : http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html

I am still looking for IOS and Kindle.

Comment: Does it able to add one flag into all of your app implementations meaning platform?

Comment: Add some parameters with parameter values that only your app knows of.

Comment: @busylee: I am assuming we need platform support to enable this. So its going to be a different implementation for each platform.

Comment: @greenapps: Adding parameters is weak. APKs can be easily decompiled to retrieve the parameters